# Does the chrome API provide a way to add items to chrome's reading list?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a chrome extension which I can use to directly add items to chrome's reading list. I have checked [Chrome API Reference for bookmarks](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/) but I did not find what I was looking for. Does anyone know to programmatically add items the Chrome's reading list?

Comment: It's not implemented. You can suggest it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: If you can, please comment back here if you create an issue in Chrome for this (I'll add my $0.02 of support) or get an update. I desperately want a keyboard shortcut to "Add to reading list" and would use a Chrome extension just to implement it, but the API needs to be there first.

Comment: I create a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1265326

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as of Feb 2023, it is not currently part of the API.

However the feature request has been logged in the Chromium issue tracker as [#1238372](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1238372)

In [a December 2022 comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1238372#c16) the issue owner said *"looking into creating an extensions API for the reading list sometime in summer 2023. No promises on if we meet this timeline but this is the goal."*